Почему проблема в отступах и как ее решить ? TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if(message.text == "Добавить Событие"):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="На какую дату?",)
        
        datese = message.text   
        
        db_table_val(date=datese)

